# Rails iterate over objects array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do something like this

```
@groups = Community::GroupMember.where(:member_id => current_user.id)
      user_ids = []
      @groups.each do |group|
        user_ids << @group.community_group_members.where(:group_id =>    group.id).pluck(:member_id)
      end
```

But I get error NoMethodError - undefined method `community_group_members' I think im not iterating @groups properly the way I want.

Comment: Are you receiving any data back from your `Community::GroupMember.where(:member_id => current_user.id)` call?

Answer (score 2):

You should have:

```
user_ids << group.community_group_members.pluck(:member_id)
```

(`group` instead of `@group`). It's because inside `each` block, the element of your array is represented by local variable (which is unprefixed) instead of instance variable (prefixed by `@`). So `@group` instance variable is unset and thus evaluated to `nil`, which doesn't respond to `community_group_members` method.

Also, I deleted your `where` clause, since it's reduntant - you're already doing this in `group.community_group_members` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
@groups = Community::GroupMember.where(:member_id => current_user.id)
      user_ids = []
      @groups.each do |group|
        user_ids << group.community_group_members.where(:group_id =>    group.id).pluck(:member_id)
      end
```

Does using the block variable group instead of @group work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two models `Community::Group` and `Community::GroupMember` with associations `has_many :community_group_members` and `belongs_to :community_group` respectively, your first line:

```
@groups = Community::GroupMember.where(:member_id => current_user.id)
```

returns an array of `Community::GroupMember` instances, i.e. group *members*, not groups.

To get the associated groups you could use [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
@group_members = Community::GroupMember.where(member_id: current_user.id)
@groups = @group_members.map { |group_member| group_member.community_group }
```

or a [join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables):

```
@groups = Community::Group.joins(:community_group_members).where(community_group_members: { member_id: current_user.id })
```

You can now retrieve the `member_id`s with:

```
user_ids = Community::GroupMember.where(group_id: @groups).pluck(:member_id)
```